# How do I output a list of variables as then change within a loop?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, I'm currently trying to use document.getElementById to make the list but it is only outputting the last value of my variable v. I'm new to programming so I am not sure how to go about making it display the list of odd numbers the correct way.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sum of odd numbers between one and the input</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Defining Table
 * Input: User inputs a number (n)
 * Processing: add all the odd intergers between 1 and the input (n)
 * Output: The sum
 */
function oddSum() {
var number = document.getElementById("input").value;
var n = parseFloat (number);
var sum = 0;


for (v = 1; v <= n ; v +=2){

document.getElementById("v").innerHTML = v;

sum += v;

}

document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = sum;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>                             
Input a number <input type="text" id="input">    
<button type="button" onclick="oddSum()">Sum of odd</button>
<br> <br> 
Here are the odd numbers. <div id="v"></div>
<br> Here is the sum of the odd numbers. <div id="outputDiv"></div>


</body>       
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML replaces the inner html of the element, it does not append new content to what you already have.

Maybe try

```
document.getElementById("v").innerHTML += v;
```

Also check this : https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-append :)

Comment: Thanks that worked, I feel like there is a different way I should be approaching it though.

Comment: hmm, I don't see any problem with your for loop. What do you think is the issue?

Comment: I guess you could store all the output in a string and then changing the innerHTML...

Comment: I guess there is not a problem, I don't really understand how adding a + before the =  made it work though. Can you explain? Thanks either way.

Comment: Ah it's a shorthand, common in many programming languages.
Instead of writing 
document.getElementById("v").innerHTML = document.getElementById("v").innerHTML + v;

you use +=

Comment: Alright cool, so you can use this so it writes the new value instead of replacing it. Is that right?

Comment: yeah.
Simpler example: x += 1 is like writing x = x + 1

Comment: How do I have it put a space between numbers it lists?

Comment: document.getElementById("v").innerHTML += v + " ";

Comment: Thanks a ton. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly the same, but I made this in a JS fiddle to demonstrate the logic. https://jsfiddle.net/mtg7g3oz/ You want to exclude the number 1 from the count, right? Just replace *prompt* with *input element* and *alert* with *output div innerhtml*

```
var input = prompt('please enter a number.');
var total = 0;
for(var i=1;i<input;i+=2){
    total += i;
}
alert(total-1);
```

Comment: Yea i want to exclude 1. Thanks that helps me understand better.

Comment: I'm happy it helped Jice. If it answers your question, please mark it as correct answer so future onlookers will find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of why you are only getting the last element is that the innerHTML method takes the element that you are targeting clears it and then replaces its content with the content that you are assigning through your variable. So at the end all you'll have is the last element.

[innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

I believe you are trying to build a DOM elements. To do that you have to use another method.